# Highcharts mouse tracking/mouseover feature is slow on chrome but not slow in firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, highcharts

We have a webapp built using Codeigniter and PHP which uses the Highcharts library and javascript/html on the client side and is deployed on IIS.

The Highcharts library renders various charts on a screen, 5 to be precise. Each chart renders data having not more than 1000 rows.

The charts are plotted fine, but when the mouse is hovered around the chart, the mouse over is displayed in frames(only on chrome). Please see image below showing the frame lags caused by mouse tracking.

[image]

**Surprisingly this behavior is observed only on chrome but not in IE or firefox.**

Can anybody help by suggesting how to overcome this bad mouse tracking on chrome. Highcharts has a mouse tracker disable option, but we loose interactivity and mouse over features if it is disabled.

Any help to overcome this or improve the mouseover frame rendering on chrome will be deeply appreciated.

Using Highcharts version 2.0.4 , Now updated to latest version 4.0.4

Tooltip code is below, using the basic tooltip option for box and area chart.

```
tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                        return 'The value for <b>' + this.x + '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>, in series '+ this.series.name;
                       //return "hello";
             }
        }
```

Comment: Is there anyway to provide us with a example, to try to debug? Otherwise the pool of people who might possibly know the answer is severely reduced.

Comment: @HristoValkanov, updated. I am using the basic tooltip option of Highcharts. Working great on IE and firefox but not on chrome. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Have you tried updating both chrome and the library? There seem to be many issues with webkit and highcharts but they are supposedly fixed in the latest versions.

Comment: @HristoValkanov, updated chrome but still no improvement. Will try using latest version of Highcharts and get back. Thanks

Comment: Highcharts is currently on version 4. You might want to use the most current version before reporting bugs on old software.

Comment: @BentOnCoding, yes will use latest and check. And how is this reporting a bug. Wow, that was unnecessary.

Comment: @HristoValkanov, now using latest version of Highcharts as advised, still no improvement. Any other suggestion/ workaround ??

Comment: It would be easier to solve with a jsfiddle

Comment: Probably it is related with known bug in Chrome reported [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/mac/Beta/iowS3DZmebo)

Comment: @sebastianBochan, yes looks like the same issue. Will go through and get back with the results. Thanks.

Comment: @SebastianBochan, thank you. The link you gave helped me solve the problem. We have to enable the "Disable layer squashing " option on chrome from here chrome://flags/#disable_layer_squashing                        If you can put it as an answer I will go ahead and mark it as solved.

Comment: @HristoValkanov, got it solved by enabling the "Disable layer squashing " option on chrome from here chrome://flags/#disable_layer_squashing  Thanks for your effort and time.

Comment: @BentOnCoding, got it solved by enabling the "Disable layer squashing " option on chrome from here chrome://flags/#disable_layer_squashing. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @ArunPadmanabhan please write it as an answer bellow and accept it as correct in order to help the future generations, facing the same problem :)

Comment: This is a valid problem.  But, I don't think the selected answer here is the correct one.

Comment: Posted a proof below that Chrome fails.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, below is the fix.

**We have to enable the "Disable layer squashing " option on chrome from here** chrome://flags/#disable_layer_squashing

P.S Thanks to @SebastianBochan and @HristoValkanov for guiding me to the solution.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. You can't tell everyone who accesses your site with chrome to enable this flag in their browser.

Comment: Just to be clear: Disable_Layer_Quashing was disabled and removed from Chrome on 2014-04-23 (see https://codereview.chromium.org/246893017).  This post is from 5 months after!  Here's an idea -- update your software to the most recent version before trying out gimmicky fixes.

Comment: +1 to @Gopherkhan 's point!  Most people will outright be scared of why do you want to be manipulating with flags (given casual users have no idea what it is and an experienced user will just nope out of there). Also, don't be so quick with marking your answer answer as Solution please. Give other people a chance, just because something worked for you doesn't mean it's necessarily the best answer

Answer (score 0):

This ***was*** a bug in Webkit.  Here is the official, Chromium bug report :

[Bugs.Webkit : hover over table rows causes the whole table to repaint](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26662)

This was fixed per the *2014-11-14 08:53:09 PST* update of Webkit, as noted in the ticket above.  This is only two months after the post by the OP.

If you are still having problems, for instance with *drag and drop* (like I am), then look at this bug report, still active and unresolved :

[Bugs.Chromium : Drag and drop performance issue when using "position:relative" style with many cells](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=358218)

It has been active since:  Mar 31 2014

> **What is the expected result?**
>
> - When the dragged object is over a cell, the cell should have a red background.
>
> **What happens instead?**
>
> - Drag and drop is very slow.
> - Cells are sometimes displayed in red, but after a few seconds.
> - Cursor pointer is not available during half a second after the drag end.