# Reactjs takes too much time for content download in chrome?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

**Scenario**:

I have a page which loads additional data when scrolled to the end of the page. Most of the times the Content Download is slow and some times it is fast. Though, the response data is only few kb. This issue is only seen in chrome *(Chrome Version: Version 67.0.3396.99 (Official Build) (64-bit))*.

What might be the solution here?

In chrome, Content Download takes sometimes shorter time and sometimes longer time for same request.

[image: Shorter time]

[image: Longer time]

The requests are to the same API.

[image: Profiling]

[As suggested here, that frontend might be doing a lot of work!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46715530/6892277)
So, I checked the profiling and it is not the issue.

Why is there a lot of idle time in the second call? How to reduce the Content Download time?

*Edit*
When click event is triggered in browser during loading, the content loads faster.

Comment: Difference may very well be cached versus non-cached.  Even then, delay could be anywhere, giving order in probability -- mysql delay (or memcached misconfig/misfire?), routing problem, dns issue? (chrome uses google dns built-in), etc., etc..

Comment: Is there something that can be done improve this issue? Other browsers are rendering it properly

Comment: It's more about finding than improving the issue.  You say "other browsers" work fine.  What about Chrome-based browsers, like Opera or Chromium?  If those work fine, it may be a problem with your testing machine; if they don't, it may be something else.  Even a dusty cable can randomly add latency to a connection, and maybe Chrome is the only one doing that extra-checking.

Comment: Also, when I click anywhere in the DOM after the request is sent, it loads instantly. I couldn't figure out the behavior

Comment: Same thing happens in Opera too..

Comment: There's really not enough info to go on here.  There are known issues with the HTML5 Drag & Drop interface that only affect Chrome-based browsers (like Opera), just search the 100's of Chrome problem here: https://www.chromium.org/issue-tracking .  But I don't even know what your app is doing.

Comment: Take a look here (accepted answer here is incorrect, but it may enlighten you): https://stackoverflow.com/q/25791379/2430549

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174742/discussion-between-sabbiu-shah-and-holdoffhunger).